# Removing item from list on other activity

Tags: android, listview, button

How can I remove a item from a `ListActivity` from a button on another Activity, the thing is,

I have this `ListActivity`:

```
public class ListaEventos extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onRestart();
        republicar();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.lista_eventos, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.criar_evento:
                Intent criar = new Intent(this, CriarEvento.class);
                startActivity(criar);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void republicar() {
        List<DadosEvento> eventos = MySingleton.getInstance().getEventos();
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DadosEvento>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, eventos));
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {

        DadosEvento clickNumber = MySingleton.getInstance().getEventos().get(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExibirEvento.class);
        Bundle exibirEvento = new Bundle();
        exibirEvento.putString("exibirNome", clickNumber.getNome());
        exibirEvento.putString("exibirData", clickNumber.getData());
        exibirEvento.putString("exibirEnd", clickNumber.getEndereco());
        exibirEvento.putString("exibirTel", clickNumber.getTel());
        intent.putExtras(exibirEvento);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**Other Activity:**

```
public class ExibirEvento extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exibir_evento);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle exibirEvento = intent.getExtras();

        String exibirNome = exibirEvento.getString("exibirNome");
        String exibirData = exibirEvento.getString("exibirData");
        String exibirEnd = exibirEvento.getString("exibirEnd");
        String exibirTel = exibirEvento.getString("exibirTel");

        TextView exibir_nome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exibirevento_edittext_nome);
        exibir_nome.setText(exibirNome);

        TextView exibir_data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exibirevento_edittext_data);
        exibir_data.setText(exibirData);

        TextView exibir_end = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exibirevento_edittext_end);
        exibir_end.setText(exibirEnd);

        TextView exibir_tel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exibirevento_edittext_tel);
        exibir_tel.setText(exibirTel);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.exibir_evento, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void sairExibicao(View v) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Now, on the ExibirEvento is where it shows me the infos about the Party, and there I need a button that removes that item from the List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are several scenarios that you can follow.

1. Use `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity` and then override the `onActivityResult` method and catch a proper `requestCode` and `result` (e. g. `RESULT_OK`) and delete current item and `notifyDataChanged` the `adapter`
2. Use singelton class, create newInstance, set values, and then refere to it from `ExibirEvento`
3. Use the database, and take advantage of `ContentProvider` and `Loader`, and pass only the `ID` of the entry to `ExibirEvento`

I think that the 3 option is the best way to go for.

Comment: in my code i use singleton, but what values and how to get then?

Comment: The values you are putting into the `Intent`